# Merging tree-like structure in OpenJPA?

Tags: java, openjpa

I am trying to build a composite tree-like structure using **OpenJPA 2.1** consisting of these classes:

`Criterion` - base, abstract class,

`SingleCriterion` - actual tree leaf,

`CompositeCriterion` - actual tree node

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="dtype",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Criterion implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
    private Criterion owner;
}

public class SimpleCriterion extends Criterion{
    @Column(name="comparison_op")
    private String op;

    @Column(name="simple_field_name")
    private String fieldName;

    @Column(name="simple_param_1")  
    private String fieldParam1;

    @Column(name="simple_param_2")  
    private String fieldParam2;
}

public class CompositeCriterion extends Criterion{
    @Column(name="composite_name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="logical_op")  
    private LogicalOp op;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Criterion> criterions;
}
```

As you can see, nothing too fancy there....

Now, both reading and persisting the whole tree works like a charm thanks to `CascadeType`. But a problem arises when I try to delete `CompositeCriterion` node because it deletes that node and runs DELETE query on the children which, naturally, are not there because of `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint within the database table. This results in `OptimisticLockException`  being thrown

I have tried many things, including:

- putting `@Dependant` annotation on `criterions` inside the
  CompositeCriterion
- adding `CascadeType.REMOVE` or `CascadeType.ALL`
- adding `orphanRemoval=true` (as it is in code above)

... but I still keep getting `OptimisticLockException` thrown ...

I'm lost! Does anyone have any advice on what to try next?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the following property :

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
```

[Additional documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_schema_info_factory)

Comment: Hell yeah! This is the solution to my problem! Thanks a lot Rick! :)